# A tag for intermittent problems

Tags: discussion, tags

I wanted to retag this question to reflect that it is an intermittent problem.

[Occasional trouble idling](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/occasional-trouble-idling#33544)

Do we really not have a tag for intermittent problems, or am I missing something?

Comment: Do we have one now?

Comment: @DucatiKiller yes we do

Comment: I guess I will begin to use it while editing   :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that we didn't. We do now ;-)

There's 300-odd questions with the word 'intermittent'. Perhaps a mass retag isn't such a good idea, a few at a time might be better...

Comment: Thanks a bunch Nick

Comment: It seems that there are just 180 odd questions: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/search?q=intermittent+is%3Aquestion

Comment: ah, I forgot to check for just questions...